# NullPointerException while using RunningCount Aggregation with Engine API

Tags: birt

I'm trying to upgrade my application to use BIRT 3.7.1 version. Currently I'm using version 2.6.0.

I'm using the latest stable release 3.7.1.

During my testing I'm facing an exception with a report which is using a serial number(RunningCount Aggregation). This exception comes when I uses the report with the Report Engine API, if I uses the web viewer the report is working fine.

I've attached a small test case to recreate the issue. This includes the report design file and a class where I'm using there ReportEngine to generate the report.

Please find the error log below:

```
Jan 3, 2012 4:34:42 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask doRun
SEVERE: An error happened while running the report. Cause:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.util.IOUtil.writeInt(IOUtil.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.util.IOUtil.writeObject(IOUtil.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleGroupCalculator.next(SimpleGroupCalculator.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet.next(SimpleResultSet.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.ResultSetWrapper.next(ResultSetWrapper.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ResultIterator.hasNextRow(ResultIterator.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ResultIterator.nextRow(ResultIterator.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ResultIterator.next(ResultIterator.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.next(QueryResultSet.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ListingElementExecutor.hasNextChild(ListingElementExecutor.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.eclipse.birt.test.RunningCountFieldTest.main(RunningCountFieldTest.java:52)
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.eclipse.birt.test.RunningCountFieldTest.main(RunningCountFieldTest.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.util.IOUtil.writeInt(IOUtil.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.util.IOUtil.writeObject(IOUtil.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleGroupCalculator.next(SimpleGroupCalculator.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.SimpleResultSet.next(SimpleResultSet.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.ResultSetWrapper.next(ResultSetWrapper.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ResultIterator.hasNextRow(ResultIterator.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ResultIterator.nextRow(ResultIterator.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ResultIterator.next(ResultIterator.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.next(QueryResultSet.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ListingElementExecutor.hasNextChild(ListingElementExecutor.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
    ... 2 more
```

You can find a sample program to recreate the issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/arunpjohny/BIRT-3.7.1-RunningCount-Error).

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by separating both `run` and `render` tasks of the `Report Engine API`.

Instead of using `IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);` run both `IRunTask runTask = engine.createRunTask(design);` and `IRenderTask renderTask = engine.createRenderTask(iReportDocument);` separatly.